# File dialog is throwing unknown error

Tags: java, savefiledialog

Hi this is a save function for my program, this is the first time using "file dialog function" it is throwing an error I am not sure how to fix it.

> The constructor FileDialog(Frame, String, int) is ambiguous

```
import java.awt.FileDialog;

public class save {
    private void initialize() {
        FileDialog fileOutputDialog =
            new FileDialog(null, "Output File", FileDialog.SAVE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fyi, your question is confusing because we don't use the word "throw" when referring to a compile-time problem.

Comment: Any particular reason why you decided to use this class instead of [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html)? [How To Use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).

Comment: @Chris Martin: Sorry I'm still kinda new to this forum I was just using "throw" because thats what we use in our discussions about coding in class. But in future I'll be sure to use the proper term!

Comment: @Predi I felt it would be easier and cleaner for the future features i need to implement in this code. (choice of encryption between several different forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
FileDialog fileOutputDialog = new FileDialog(new Frame(), "Save file", FileDialog.SAVE);
```

instead of

```
FileDialog fileOutputDialog = new FileDialog(null, "Output File", FileDialog.SAVE);
```

Answer (score 1):

`FileDialog` has two constructors of interest for this problem:

```
public FileDialog(Frame parent, String title, int mode)

public FileDialog(Dialog parent, String title, int mode)
```

If you call your constructor with a `null` first argument, how does the compiler know which constructor you want to call?

A better way to handle this would be to declare a variable of the right type, set it to `null`, and use that as the first argument instead. The static type of that variable allows the compiler to figure out which constructor you want.

For example, if you want the `Frame` constructor:

```
Frame unusedFrame = null;
FileDialog fileOutputDialog = new FileDialog(unusedFrame, "Output File", FileDialog.SAVE);
```